# Open photo gallery with a particular image

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I open the photo gallery browser with a particular image for an iOS/Android device? My app saves images in the device's photo gallery. If I use `ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)` using the [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) plugin, it shows the photo gallery with all the recently saved photos. How can I show the image I recently saved within the gallery app?

Comment: It looks like you'll have to implement a custom view yourself.

Comment: You can choose to save the latest image picked in something like Shared Preferences and then you'll always have a pointer to the latest image picked. What do you think?

Comment: @VipinKumarKashyap But how do you access that "pointer" using the `image_picker` library, since that opens up to _all_ images.